# Javascript Session Data Storage

Tags: javascript, storage, google-gears, jstore

Does anyone know of a reliable way to store data to use across pages of a site?... Here is what I've found so far:

1. Cookies - Not enough capacity to store what I need atm.
2. URL hash - Same as above
3. Frames - Not a method I would use atm.
4. HTML 5 document.localStorage and document.sessionStorage - Not fully supported yet
5. [Google Gears](http://gears.google.com/) - The users of the site will most likely not have this installed
6. [YUI Storage](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/storage/) - This sounds promising... does anyone have experience using it?
7. [jStore](http://eric.garside.name/demo.html?p=jstore) - This also sounds promising, but when I tried using the demo and reloaded the page, it lost my input. Does anyone have experience with this plugin?

Note: I am not an admin of the site in question, so I don't have database privileges, but I am able to add scripting.

---

Edit: I found this interesting site that saves [session variables](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html) in the window.name... it probably has some security issues as well

Comment: What scripting language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dojo has a cool plugin that uses flash for a local storage. Plus it abstracts it so if they have gears or an html5 browser it will use that instead

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden"
```

store the value in it, the info comes back from the page together with the info, and after you send it to another page, and so on

Comment: I don't think this method would work between pages of my site. Sending the data to another page would save the data into the URL much like php does, which for me is too limited. I may be wrong, but I don't think this would work for me.

Comment: store the data on the server and send to the client an id that is going to identify the data from the server

Comment: Sadly I don't have server access.. I am actually the client trying to get more from a site which does allow me to save scripts and HTML.

Comment: than just save it into some file or something

Comment: I can't save files that way either. File management is all done through an online interface. So no ftp address or anything like that is available.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use server-sides sessions?

Comment: Sorry, no I can't. See the comments above for more information.